# What is it called - Example a Debian server with only limited system features

Tags: linux, debian, unix

I came across a word which I don't remember correctly. Basically, unlike Ubuntu 16.04 server (has a lot of stuff installed by default), there are servers like Debian with only very limited softwares.

So when you want to install some software, it gives you a list of lot of other software/libraries that is required since it is somewhat a locked-down server (not the right word, but I'm looking for the correct word so I could do some research).

Comment: You mean like a [Debian Minimal Server](https://www.tecmint.com/installation-of-debian-9-minimal-server/)?

Comment: You could also be talking about Net Install images which usually only have a really basic set of commands in order to setup the system.

Comment: @n8te I think minimal make sense.  But the word I'm looking for isn't that. I've seen that word recruiters using that in their requirement to manage stuff. Like "should have experience in managing locked down servers.." Any guesses?

Comment: "Hardened"? While there are many ways to make a server more secure ("harden it"), one common thing is to have a minimal amount of software to reduce possible exploits.

Comment: [Embedded Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_operating_system)?